# Intellij IDEA cannot find Python tests

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA Python plugin for Python development. I'm writing tests using Unittests module. I've read, we can toggle between test and method being tested using <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. However, Intellij cannot find any tests and prompts to create a new test.

How can I link the source method with the test method?

My directory structure is

```
|-update_app_node.py
|Tests
   |- test_update_app_node.py
```